# Como mudar o idioma das exceções lançadas durante os testes automatizados

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

Usando Eclipse (IBM RAD Studio), Maven e JUnit, quando uma exceção é lançada durante a execução dos testes a mensagem é mostrada em português. Eu gostaria que fosse mostrada em inglês.

Exemplo:

`org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Um Driver JDBC ou um nome de classe DataSource deve ser especificado na propriedade ConnectionDriverName.`

Erro completo:

```
CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "getAll" on bean "BeanId(embeddable#classes#CarRepo, null)". Exception data: <openjpa-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:778978M-OPENJPA-975 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Um Driver JDBC ou um nome de classe DataSource deve ser especificado na propriedade ConnectionDriverName.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:784)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:561)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1265)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:505)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:430)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:103)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:863)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:854)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:638)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:183)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:27)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEMPool.getEntityManager(JPAEMPool.java:170)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.getEMInvocationInfo(JPATxEntityManager.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.getEMInvocationInfo(JPATxEntityManager.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEntityManager.persist(JPAEntityManager.java:143)
    at com.learning.business.car.CarRepo.getAll(CarRepo.java:19)
    at com.learning.business.car.EJSLocalNSLCarRepo_a1ab5865.getAll(EJSLocalNSLCarRepo_a1ab5865.java)
    at com.learning.business.car.CarRepoTest.testGetCarsByEjb(CarRepoTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Como eu posso configurar meu ambiente para que esta mensagem do exemplo seja mostrada em inglês?

Comment: Já tentou alterar o Locale ?

Comment: @JosuéEduardo Mudar o Locale onde e como?

Comment: Utilize os parâmetros de inicialização da JVM -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en

Comment: @JosuéEduardo `-Duser.language=en` resolveu. Obrigado! Se você transformar seu comentário em resposta eu posso marcá-la como "aceita".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize os seguintes parâmetros na JVM para alterar o [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

`-Duser.language=en`;